# How to find a row where col have special characters or numbers (except hyphen,apostrophe and space) in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find rows where col have special characters or numbers (except hyphen,apostrophe and space) in Oracle SQL.

I am doing like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  Name_test LIKE '%[^A-Za-z _]%'
```

But It is not working and I also need to exclude any apostrophe.
Kindly help.

Comment: Your code is not a valid pattern in Oracle SQL.  In all likelihood, it is doing nothing useful.

Comment: `like` uses wildcards `%` and `_`. `regex_like` uses regular expressions, which don't include `%`.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find all rows where column have ONLY numbers and special characters (and you can specify all of required special characters):

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  regexp_like(Name_test, q['^[0-9'%#@]+$]')
```

as you can see you just need to add your special characters after 0-9.
^ - start
$ - end

About format q'[SOMETHING]' please see TEXT LITERALS here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA

If you need to find all rows where column have no alpha-characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  regexp_like(Name_test, '^[^a-zA-Z]*$');
```

or
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  regexp_like(Name_test, '^\W*$');

about \W - please see "Table 8-5 PERL-Influenced Operators in Oracle SQL Regular Expressions" here:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS235

Comment: regexp_like(Name_test, q['^[0-9'%#@]+$]') syntax is giving error.                 
 And also I need the pattern where I have alphabets, Numbers or Special Characters {except hyphen(-),apostrophe (') and Space}.

Comment: You have a typo: should be q'[ instead of q['

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find rows where col have special characters or numbers (except hyphen, apostrophe and space [and presumably single quotes]) in Oracle SQL.

You can use double single quotes to put a single quote in:

```
WHERE  Name_test LIKE '%[^-A-Za-z _'']%'
```

However, this is not Oracle syntax.  If the above works, then I would guess you are using SQL Server.  In Oracle:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Name_test, '[^A-Za-z _'']')
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon now I am doing as below:                                                                             AND (REGEXP_LIKE(trim(NAME_1), '[^A-Za-z -'']')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(trim(NAME_2), '[^A-Za-z -'']')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(trim(NAME_3), '[^A-Za-z -'']'))  , still I am getting hyphen in my results.

Comment: @KaushalTalniya . . . Make the hyphen the first character in the list.

Comment: Actually those special characters comes in between of the name of any person , hence I need to exclude A-Z from my query and then condition will be like....AND (REGEXP_LIKE(trim(NAME_1), '[^- '']')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(trim(rap07.NAME_2), '[^- '']')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(trim(rap07.NAME_3), '[^- '']')). I think this should work.

Comment: @KaushalTalniya . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  Ask a *new* question.  Provide a clear explanation, sample data, and desired results.